# .NET Core Web API Authentication and .NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity, jwt

I recently took over a .NET core MVC project and have to extend it with an API. For authentication .NET core Identity is used. Coming from swift iOS/Mac development i started a demo project getting into it and doing some basic authentication.

When reading up on the identity on [Microsofts Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) they foucs on WebApps. So my questions are:

- Should i use identity for API authentication or is it just for internal identity Management and WebApp stuff?
- Does identity/.NET core already offer me jwt and e.g. basic auth to initially obtain the jwt or do i have to create a lot myself?

My Goal rn is to just create jwt-auth protected routes and to be able to get a jwt with a username and a password.

Comment: use identity server 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Core Identity isn't suitable for guarding APIs, usage of other identity providers is directed by the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio):

> ASP.NET Core Identity adds user interface (UI) login functionality to
> ASP.NET Core web apps. **To secure web APIs and SPAs, use one of the**
> **following**:
>
> - Azure Active Directory
> - Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C)
> - IdentityServer4

and as per the previous link:

> IdentityServer4 is an OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 framework for
> ASP.NET Core. IdentityServer4 enables the following security features:
>
> - Authentication as a Service (AaaS)
> - Single sign-on/off (SSO) over multiple application types
> - Access control for APIs
> - Federation Gateway

So you will need to go with [IdentityServer4](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.0/)

Comment: Thanks, that's what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should use identity server4 for this.

Refer a simple example of identity server 4 to protect client with token.

[identity-server4 simple example](https://damienbod.com/2017/04/14/asp-net-core-identityserver4-resource-owner-password-flow-with-custom-userrepository/)

There are a lot more things you will have to understand refer [identity server 4 official doc](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Moreover you can also follow [step by step identity server setup video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOeFnOV9YBa7dnrjpOG6lMpcyd7Wn7E8V).

Comment: youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOeFnOV9YBa7dnrjpOG6lMpcyd7Wn7E8V ..you can refer this also ..step by step setup